# On Azure Boards can I create a 'rule' to automatically assign the 'committed' state when a backlog item is assigned to an iteration/sprint?

Tags: azure-devops

Wondering if we can create a 'rule' on Azure Boards to automatically assign the 'committed' state of a backlog item is assigned to an iteration/sprint? Currently when editing a process, you can assign a 'rule' to each item but it seems the rules can only be based on a limited subset of fields/data and iteration/sprint isn't one of them.

Ideally when we put an item in a sprint, we'd like it to just become 'committed' instead of manually having to change it. I know i can probably accomplish this with  web hooks but was hoping it might be possible with the rules engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this awesome extension tool `Work item form one click actions` which enables you do this. [Click here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohitbagra.witoneclickactions) to install it to your project.

1,Install `Work item form one click actions` from the marketplace.
You can find `WIT One click actions` is added to the project setting page and the work item page

At the end of project setting page

[image]

**Work item page**

[image]

2, **click the eclipse to open your personal rule group and add a new rule.**

[image]

3, **set the triggers and actions**

[image]

4,After you complete adding the rule. It will appear in `WIT One click actions` field in the work item setting page. You can then test the rule for yourself.

[Click here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohitbagra.witoneclickactions) for more information about how to use this extension.

Comment: This looks great! I'll have to check it out to see if it works for me but certainly looks promising